# Simulate website loading time

Tags: loading, simulate

I want to try to see how much faster a website can load on a server, without having to copy the entire site over first. I have an idea of how I can do that, but I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something, and I'm not sure the best way to do what I am trying to do.

If I use a website like Pingdom, I can see the number of files that are loaded for a given URL, and the size of each of those files.

I want to create a page in PHP that can simulate the loading of these files. I assume I can do this by calling a file on my server that can generate files with a size I specify. So, for example, I could call this file more than once, with a file size appended in the query string, and the browser would download those files.

Maybe I can generate images on the fly that will be the file size I specify?

Would this idea work, or is there something I'm overlooking?

If this is possible, how would I generate these files?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's exactly what you are looking for, but in Google Chrome there is an option to simulate a connection speed. When you open the developer tools, you can go in the Network tab and to the right of "Disable cache" you will see "No throttling" which is a drop-down and you can select the internet speed you want to simulate.

Comment: Not what I am trying to do. I want to be able to look at any website at all, see how long it takes to load. Then simulate the same site on my own server to see what the loading time would be.

Comment: This is impossible. You would need to have the code and be able to run it on your server.

Comment: Wouldn't I just need to simulate the same amount of data and requests? I'm not trying to get a visual simulation of the site. I'm trying to simulate the same amount of data, and same number of files. As a simple example, if a website had 10 requests for images, each at 50kb, and the page code was 5kb, wouldn't I just need to simulate 10 requests for images of 50kb and a text file of 5kb in order to compare the speed?

Comment: You could try that I guess. Although it won't take into account any server-side or client-side processing unless you recreate the exact same situation.